# iPhone is not available using IOS 13.6 and XCode 11.5. Please reconnect the device

Tags: xcode, flutter

I'm using IPhone SE using  IOS 13.6 and XCODE Version 11.5 (11E608c)...I am getting this error message when running flutter on the connected device.
I tried to restart mac and still not working...thank you...

Answer (score 1):

Xcode 11.5 cannot handle a device running iOS 13.6. Either install Xcode 11.6 (currently in beta) or install an earlier version of iOS on your phone. For a more detailed explanation, read the following article:

[Xcode and New iOS Versions](https://www.meandmark.com/blog/2017/12/xcode-and-new-ios-versions/)

Comment: Thank you @Mark Szymczyk....will try to download Xcode 11.6 or downgrade my ios version on my phone...